# How can I see all available reltool overlay template variables?

Tags: erlang, rebar

I have a fairly standard OTP setup with rebar and reltool. I've setup reltool to use a vars.config to swap in overlay template variables with `{overlay_vars, "files/vars.config"}.` I've noticed that variables other than what I have listed in vars.config also work as overlay template variables, the most obvious one of which is `{{erts_vsn}}`.

I assume there are other built-in variables; how do I find what they are? I've combed the reltool docs and come up with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your answer is in Rebar's [`rebar_reltool`](https://github.com/basho/rebar/blob/master/src/rebar_reltool.erl) module.
There, you find the definition for:

- erts_vsn
- rel_vsn
- target_dir